# eslint force check key in object to equal undefined

Tags: javascript, eslint

When you check if `obj` contains `key` you can use

```
var key = 'somekey'
if (obj[key]) {
   ...
}
```

However, this could leak some bugs when `obj[key] === 0` or `obj[key] === false` so it is better to use `obj[key] === undefined`. But this short hand check has ingrained in my muscle memory.

Is there eslint rule to enforce check `=== undefined` do smell check so I will realize this bug early?